# Persistent fluorescence

Tags: atomic-physics, fluorescence

I have some mineral specimens that exhibit fluorescence. For example, I have a piece of scapolite and it turns bright orange if I shine a UV light on it, but if I remove the light, it immediately goes dark. Then I also have a piece of selenite which does not shine so brightly, but when I remove the light it keeps glowing faint green, as though it is storing up the energy of the light somehow. How does it store up the energy?

Comment: You may want to do this experiment with white light on green plants. You will get red [fluorescence from chlorophyll](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chlorophyll_fluorescence)
for a few seconds.

Answer (score 2):

I believe what you are experiencing is the difference between [fluorescence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluorescence) and [phosphorescence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phosphorescence). The energy absorbed from the UV light is stored in excited electron states in the mineral in both cases, but in the case of phosphorescence the energy is stored for a much longer time (long enough for you to notice) because the transition back to the ground state (which causes the light emission) is a so-called "forbidden" transition. "Forbidden" does not mean that it cannot happen, but it is very unlikely compared to a non-forbidden transition and therefore the energy-dissipation takes much longer time. Fluorescence happens on the 
time scale of a few nanoseconds, while phosphorescence happens on the time scale of minutes or even hours.

Comment: Why would it take minutes or hours in one case, but only nanoseconds in the other?

Comment: @TylerDurden: Wikipedia has a [good article on phosphorescence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phosphorescence) that explains why the final transition to the ground state is slow.

Comment: Because different materials are made of different molecules with different spatial structure and different properties of their electronic hull. Some excited molecules have electrons that oscillate and radiate with great intensity, while others oscillate and radiate weakly. This can be (in principle) explained based on time-dependent Schroedinger's equation together with the formula for retarded EM field due to oscillating charge distribution.